# Вопрос о 'соли' хэширования

Tags: безопасность, хеширование, криптография

Только что читаю статью о защите данных сайта, а там такая строчка:

```
у двух пользователей с паролем «123456» будут разные соли «соль1» и «соль2»
```

Вопрос: 
Как сделать так, чтобы соль для каждого пользователя был новым, как сказано выше?

Как я читал, соль мы задаем какому то переменному, затем конкатенацией привязываем к паролю пользователя. Но в этом случае соль для всех одинаковая. Так как быть?

Comment: `salt:hash`

Comment: Google не выдал ничего по данному запросу. Подробнее можно? Хотяб ключевые слова

Comment: начнем с основ. хэш функция это такая функция `y = f(x)`, для которой нет других вариантов как найти `x`, зная `y` кроме как прямой перебор.  
  
соответсвенно как и для некоторых методов шифрования слабые стороны проявляются когда используют простые пароли и/или взлом методом подбора по словарю.  
  
соответственно чем длинее пароль при шифровании или входные данные при хэшировании, тем сложнее взлом. именно поэтому соль исопльзуется для искуственного увеличения сложности взлома

Comment: соль используется просто для того, чтобы в уже посчитанных базах хэшей нельзя было бы найти подходящий пароль. и это важно, только для безопасности ваших пользователей, а не данных, т.к. если Чак имеет доступ к вашей базе данных, то вряд-ли что-то сможет остановить его от сброса пароля любому юзеру и повышения его прав до администратора.

Answer (score 6):

Стандартным способом является хранение соли в БД с привязкой к id юзера. При этом принято:

1. Усложнять механизм вычисления хэша из пароля+соли, скажем многократным применением хэша или модификацией функции конкатенации соли типа: 
   `hash(hash(salt/2+password+salt/2)+salt/3)` ну и т.д. - все зависит от вашей фантазии. В нормальных системах количество итераций хэша легко переваливает за несколько тысяч
2. Соль хранится в модифицированном виде, в самом простом варианте применить тупое перемешивание - как в [шифре Цезаря](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F), а еще лучше разделить соль на несколько частей и хранить части раздельно в комбинации с шифрованием соли.

Comment: вспомнилось..

>> Ты на первый замок закрыл? А на второй? а на щеколду? а веником подпер? Как не подпер - заходи, бери, что хочешь!

Comment: Если у злоумышленника есть дамп базы, то либо вы его выложили в открытый доступ (маловероятно), либо у вас открыт мускул наружу (маловероятно), либо у него есть доступ к серверу, а значит, и к вашему алгоритму. Все равно все упрется в количество итераций хэширования и стойкость алгоритма хеширования. По-моему, ничего с солью не надо делать.

Comment: Вот [свежая статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/210760/) на эту теме в Хабре.

Comment: @Fike все дело в том, что безопасность это не есть 1 большое мероприятие, а это 1000 мелких мероприятий по рублю. Понятно, что абсолютной безопасности не существует всегда найдется способ взлома. В конце-концов [терморектальный криптоанализатор](https://lurkmore.to/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) тоже никто не отменял. Речь идет о снижении вероятности взлома или по другому повышении стоимости взлома.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, ну это реально пристегивание швабры к двери и легкий способ дебажить три дня.

Comment: @Fike я видимо уже отстал от жизни и ничо не понял. Все слова мне понятны, а смысл ускользает. Поясни свой последний камент, я серьезно...

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, какова вероятность того, что разбирающийся в криптографии и имеющий солидные мощности для подбора хешей злоумышленник доберется до базы и не доберется до вашего алгоритма перестановки букв/не поймет его/пропустит его? На сколько это его задержит? На час, на два? По-моему такой способ "шифрования" сопоставим именно с той шваброй, которая подпирает закрутую на пять замков дверь. Сложность слома хэша во много раз превышает сложность нахождения алгоритма, и если нужно повысить сложность, то нужно брать более стойкий алгоритм хэширования и большее количество итераций.

Comment: @Fike, какова вероятность того, что человек с описываемыми Вами талантами начнет взламывать продукт ТС-а?

Comment: @avp, если исходить из этой логики - то тем более, зачем вообще какая-то защита кроме хэширования?

Comment: @Fike, естественно. Причем достаточно самого примитивного. 

99.99% всех хранимых данных реально никому (ну, их владельцу на 90%) вообще не нужны.

А вот система охраны действительно важных данных комплексная и часто (мягко говоря очень) неудобная. И к программированию не сводится.

Answer (score 4):

Ну так что мешает сделать генератор случайных чисел или строки? И делать как допустим в `vBulletin md5(md5($pass).$salt)`, ну и естественно соль хранить в БД с записью пользователя

Comment: А насколько легко войти/взломать БД на каком то внешнем хостинге? Т.е там требуется что то внедрить или как?

Я просто новичок в этом, в безопасности, вот и хочу тонкости узнать как можно больше

Comment: @navi1893, 99% процентов взломов - это фактически отданный злоумышленнику доступ к ресурсам приложения, т.е. у вас либо открыта база на внешнее чтение (или есть иной способ подобраться к серверу), либо через ваше приложение с помощью SQL- и не только инъекций можно покопаться в самой БД.  
Т.е. ничего, как правило, внедрять не нужно - все уже есть. Теоретически можно сбрутфорсить ssh-пароль и украсть логин/пасс к бд для локального доступа (и сразу слить дамп), но это маловероятно (хотя если вы "потеряли" ssh-пароль, то вероятность резко возрастает).

Comment: зачем вы внутренним md5 сбрасываете разнообразие пароля ?

Answer (score 3):

Еще есть вариант:

Генерировать соль из (timestamp + login + password) при конечном шаге регистрации.
Делать выжимку Хеша из рандомного числа символов диапазона, к примеру от 20 до 100(если это SHA512). Разбивать на 3 - 4 части.
И записывать в разные таблицы в БД.

Comment: Идея отличная! Как алгоритм хеширования буду использовать bcrypt. Но мне интересно еще кое что, какая то защита нужна для самой БД? @naguwal

Comment: всё зависит от БД. конечно в идеале была бы круто реализовать полную шифрацию канала между КЛИЕНТОМ(приложением) и БД. И connectionString с использованием парного ключа шифрования... Но это ресурсы и время... посему если это простой php+MySQL хостер то достаточно стандарного доступа и крон приложения которое бы раз в сутки меняло пароль к бд прописовая его в конфиге.

Comment: И я сомневаюсь о необходимости bcrypt при таком подходе на мой взгляд достаточно SHA512. В любом случае при таком подходе подобрать хэш пароля для конечного сравнения не реально!

Comment: @naguwal из статьи по ссылке выше:

> SHA512: 220 M/s
> bcrypt: 8,5 k/s

разница во времени на простой подбор в 16750 раз. Другое дело, что и создавать сам хэш на цпу наверняка примерно настолько же медленее.

Comment: А вообще весьма неплохо использовать и _SHA512_ и _bcrypt_. _SHA512_ для внешнего ключа ну и ещё чего нибудь а bycript для внутренних ключей или ключа(в зависимости от организации системы).

Answer (score 0):

Сгенерируйте ее на основе каких-то данных пользователя, которые не могут подвергнуться изменению, например из даты регистрации и логина.

Comment: Можно разбить данные пользователя на символы, а затем рандомно собрать из них новое выражение. Думаю так намного безопаснее будет. Да?